# How many budget required for generating traffic of 20M monthly?

Tags: advertising

*Hopefully its a right place to ask such question*

Assuming that in my sector average CTR is 3%, adwords click cost is 1.5$ and target audience size is about 12M, how much money I should spent for generating traffic of 20M monthly (initial investment \ ongoing investment)

Is there any research or or some source talking about this you can reference?

Comment: You want to pay for 20 million visitors per month?     How is that going to happen if the audience size isn't that big?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: usually there are return visitors. On my website right now its 25% of return visitors

Comment: Even if you expect return visitors, I don't see how you can expect to get more visitors than there are people interested in the entire sector.